# google maps reverse geocoding: passing variables

Tags: google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to get store the address correspoding to a latitude,longitude in a variable (in javascript). I created a call back function (after reading numerous posts on it) and the code is as follows. Now I want to store the address in a variable called location3.

Oddly enough, for an alert right after location3 is assigned, it is undefined. But if it is looked at 300ms later, then it gives the right value. I want to get the address assigned to location3 immediately. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
  function codeLatLng1(lat,long,callback) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
          callback(results[1].formatted_address);
          myvariable=results[1].formatted_address;
        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
}


lat1_last=37;long1_last=-100;
codeLatLng1(lat1_last,long1_last,function(locat) {location3=locat;});
alert (location3); // THIS ALERT SHOWS THAT IT IS STILL UNDEFINED
setTimeout(function(){alert (location3);},300);  // THIS ALERT GIVES THE RIGHT ADDRESS
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea to grasp here is that the 2nd argument to geocode(), a callback function, is not going to be called right away, but rather only after a result is received from Google. Meanwhile, the function codeLatLng1(), having posted the request, returns control to the caller. In your program, that means the first alert() happens next, followed by some wait time during which Google gets back to you, the callback is called, and so on.

Likewise, your anonymous callback that sets location3 is only executed when that result is received - not before codeLatLng1 returns.

It would make more sense to put your alert inside your anonymous callback.  Typically this is where final processing of the result goes.

This is an example of asynchronous or event-driven programming.

I hope this makes it clear!

Comment: Hi Eric,Thanks very much for your suggestion. Yes the alert works well inside the callback without the need for delay as you suggested. However my objective is to use value of the variable "Location3" in an infobox (I really dont need alert) - how can I assign the reverse geocoded address directly to "Location3" without the need for delay. Thanks again.

Comment: You can create the infobox inside the callback. This is good programming style. If you must create it earlier, leave it invisible, then let the callback set the label and make it visible.

Comment: There will always be a delay - you're accessing the Internet! You will find its so much easier when you put most of your code in callbacks. Still, it's more trouble than it's worth, but if you want to wait until location3 is defined, you need a loop that checks if it is still undefined every so often...